# Dynamically populating input text boxes and removing them using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

When I click the `+` button, new text box with `+` and `-` buttons should appear and this `+`button itself should disappear.

When I click the `-` button, the text box must disappear and the previous `+` button should once again appear.

Help me with making the previous buttons appear and disappear accordingly.

Here is code I have done so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button");


  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var append1 = $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><button class="add_field_button1">+</button><button class="remove_field">-</button></div>');
    $(".add_field_button").hide();

  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function() {

    $(this).parent('div').remove();

  })
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".add_field_button1", function() {

    $("#inputfield").append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><button class="add_field_button">+</button><button class="remove_field">-</button></div>');

  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div id="inputfield">
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
    <button class="add_field_button">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO LINK**](https://jsfiddle.net/yhq851we)

```js
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

$('body').on("click", '.add_field_button', function (e) {
    var _this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    _this.hide();
    _this.closest('.row').find('.remove_field').hide();

    var append1 = $(wrapper).append('<div class="row"><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><button class="add_field_button">+</button><button class="remove_field">-</button></div>');


})


$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function () {
    var _row = $(this).closest('.row');
    _row.prev('.row').find('button').show();
    _row.remove();
})
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap row">

    <div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
    <button class="add_field_button">+</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please find the below code which will work for your scenario.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button id=1 class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

I have given default id=1 to add button

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count

    $('body').on("click",".add_field_button", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(".add_field_button").hide();

           $(wrapper).append('<div> <button id='+x+' class="add_field_button"> Add More Fields </button> <input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box

            $("#"+x).show();
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        $("#"+x).show();
    })
});
```

And assigned the id=x dynamically to add button.

I have created demo of it, please find the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/xokqvxtk/ of the same

Answer (score -1):

I cannot understand the requirement fully, but from what I can get, there can be two cases:
1) Clicking on '-' button, the previous '+' button should appear.
   
For this just add the below code to your 'remove_field' click function.

```
$(".add_field_button").show();
```

2) If you want to show the previous '+' button only after all the input fields are removed, then add the following in the 'remove_field' click function.

```
var temp = $(".add_field_button1");
if(!temp) {
    $(".add_field_button").show();
}
```

In this way you can check if any of the dynamically added input fields are still there or not

Answer (score -1):

Create an another function to return the dynamic fields, Please check the code,

```
function createTexts(cnt){
    ret_str = '<div id="dv_'+cnt+'"><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><button onclick='addmore('+cnt+')' class="add_field_button">+</button><button onclick='remove('+cnt+')' class="remove_field">-</button></div>';
}
```

pass the count as cnt parameter and create function addmore for appending and remove to remove item with that created element id.

Answer (score -1):

Just check the next elment length and enable the div

```
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(){ 

$(this).parent('div').remove();
  if($( ".add_field_button" ).next( ".new-elemnt" ).length <= 0)
  $(".add_field_button").show();

})
```

for refrence https://plnkr.co/edit/q9GTxkiHa1CjEpPAoP1x?p=preview

Comment: When I click the +, new text box with + and - button should appear and this